# Can't post NSData properly via NSURLRequest

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsurlrequest

I am creating a recipe application that requires access to an online database of recipes.

Currently, I am unable to receive the data on the other end. I have, however, verified that the NSURLRequest is landing on the correct page.

Here is the request code:

***_*__*_*__.m file**

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                     timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

// store recipe
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Recipes" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryOfRecipes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfRecipes = [dictionaryOfRecipes objectForKey:@"recipesArray"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];
data = [arrayOfRecipes objectAtIndex:self.thisRecipeIndex];

// post data
[request setHTTPBody:data];

[connection start];
```

**Print Out of Data Being Sent**
     `(NSData *) $2 = 0x09071f40 {
         ingredients =     (
             "penne pasta",
             water
         );
         instructions =     (
             "put the penne in the water",
             boil
         );
         recipeName = Penne;
     }`

***_*____.php File**

```
<?php
// initialize connection to database
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');
$db_name = "project3";
mysql_select_db($db_name, $db);

// store incoming data as php variables
error_log(print_r($_POST, true));
$recipeName = $_POST['recipeName'];

// create mysql query
$query = "INSERT INTO recipeNamesTable (recipeName) VALUES '$recipeName'";
mysql_query($query);

mysql_close($db);
?>
```

I have some guesses as to what potential problems may be but am not sure if I'm correct. While `[arrayOfRecipes objectAtIndex:self.thisRecipeIndex]` is an `NSDictionary`, I store it as `NSData`, though this does not return any errors so I kept it that way. Would I need to store it as the `NSDictionary` that it is and then convert it to `NSData`? If this is not the problem, I would love to get some feedback as to what else is going wrong above.

Answer (score 2):

As you seem to have guessed, these two lines:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];
data = [arrayOfRecipes objectAtIndex:self.thisRecipeIndex];
```

don't do what you think.  The first line allocates a new empty `NSData` object and stores the pointer to that object in the `data` variable.  The second line retrieves an `NSDictionary` from the array and puts the pointer to it in the `data` variable.  You've now lost track of the empty `NSData` object that `data` used to point to.  Also, you have stored the wrong kind of pointer into the `data` variable.  That variable is supposed to hold a pointer to an `NSData` but you've put a pointer to an `NSDictionary` into it.  The compiler didn't complain because `-[NSArray objectAtIndex:]` returns an `id` which is a completely generic object pointer.  The compiler has no way of know what kind of object was actually retrieved.

So, yes, you need to decide on a communication protocol and a data interchange format that you will use to convey the information in the dictionary to the server.  Then you need to convert the dictionary into that format and send the resulting data.  You might look into `NSJSONSerialization`.